# Why is default variable off by one in function definition?

Tags: python, lambda

I found an interesting issue why trying to do a the following for a code golf challenge:

```
>>> f=lambda s,z=len(s): 5+z
>>> f("horse")
11                            #Expected 10
>>>              
>>> def g(s,z=len(s)):
...  print "z: ", z
...  print "sum: ", 5+z
...
>>> g("horse")
z:  6
sum:  11    
>>>                       
>>> len("horse") + 5           #Expected function operation
10
```

Creating the function both ways seems to initialize `z` as `6` instead of the expected `5`, why does this happen?

Comment: You can't do that. `s` doesn't exist at function definition time. This won't work outside of this specific REPL session.

Comment: You have already declared an `s` previously

Comment: Ah, yeah, starting a new session now causes this to throw a `NameError`

Comment: What you want is `f = lambda s: 5 + len(s)`

Comment: @user3100115, this was for a code golf, so I was using it to try and get a named variable `z` without declaring it on a new line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The python docs [have a page that explains this](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#what-does-happen)

> Python’s default arguments are evaluated once when the function is
>   defined, not each time the function is called

In your case, `s` must have already been bound to a string of length 6 before you created the lambda function.  When python evaluated the lambda definition with `z=len(s)`, it evaluated to `z=6`.  It doesn't get processed again each time you call the function.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use assignment in lambda expression unless the variable is already declared. In your case the variable `s` was previously declared as mentioned in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34662321/why-is-default-variable-off-by-one-in-function-defintion#comment57070180_34662321) and because `z` gets bound at runtime it used that value of `s`.

Demo:

```
>>> a = 9
>>> f = lambda b: a + b
>>> f(3)
12
>>> a = 11
>>> f(3)
14
>>> f = lambda b, a=a: a + b # "a" gets bound to previous value 11
>>> f(3)
14
>>> a = 3 # 
>>> f(3)
14
```

As you can see if you use `a=a` in the lambda expression `a` value gets bound at definition time and changing the value doesn't have any effect which is what happened in your case.

You should change your lambda expression like this:

```
>>> f = lambda s: 5 + len(s)
>>> f('horse')
10
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition won't work, because the way you have defined your default arguments. Python’s default arguments are evaluated once when the function is defined, not each time the function is called (like it is in say, Ruby). This means that if you use a mutable default argument and mutate it, you will and have mutated that object for all future calls to the function as well. Your program will not work as you see below!

[image]